# Decimal.h C++ library errors

Tags: c++, c++11, decimal

I'm learning C++ on the *PPP* Bjarne Stroustrup book. In the four chapter, i realize the double imprecision problem and i started to look for some alternative (decimal type).

I found [this](https://github.com/vpiotr/decimal_for_cpp) library, but my compiler show some errors in the lib file.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
'::max' has not been declared   chapter4.drill      line 46, external location: C:\Users\GAMEOVER\Documents\Libaries\decimal_for_cpp-master\include\decimal.h   C/C++ Problem
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
'numeric_limits' is not a member of 'std'   chapter4.drill      line 46, external location: C:\Users\GAMEOVER\Documents\Libaries\decimal_for_cpp-         master\include\decimal.h  C/C++ Problem
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
expected primary-expression before '>' token    chapter4.drill      line 46,   external location: C:\Users\GAMEOVER\Documents\Libaries\decimal_for_cpp-master\include\decimal.h C/C++ Problem
```

You can see the 46 line here:

```
#ifndef DEC_NO_CPP11
#include <cstdint>
46. #define DEC_MAX_INT32 (std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::max())
#else
#ifndef DEC_EXTERNAL_LIMITS

#ifndef __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
#define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
#endif

#if defined(__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X) || (__cplusplus >= 201103L)
#include <cstdint>
#else
#include <stdint.h>
#endif

#endif

#define DEC_MAX_INT32 INT32_MAX

#endif
```

I'm using Eclipse with MinGW + GCC (4.8.1)
Also, i setted the compiler to use C++11

*If you have any suggestions to improve my questions, say it.

Comment: Which version of gcc/g++ is included with MinGW ?

Comment: `#ifndef DEC_NO_CPP11`  But you're saying you *are* using C++ 11.

Comment: Richard, it is the 4.8.1 version

Comment: Paul, i setted of the compile version, using "-std=c++11".
I have learn the #define directive a long time ago, but i'm not sure what i have to do or if the set of c++11 is the problem.
Doesn't seems to me, but anyway... What you think i should do to fix it?

Comment: Dieter, you're right! Thank you.
I used #include <limits> and that resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's corrected now at GitHub repository. 
Please register issues related to this library at GitHub - otherwise you can be down-voted here by other people(?).

Answer (score 1):

Like Dieter said, 
you only have to include this to resolve the problem:

```
 #include <limits>
```

I hope that can help other people.